# Form submit button positing, fixed / absolute

Tags: jquery, css, forms, button, css-position

I have comments that are echoed out from my DB into their own containing divs.

In this div i have a 'hidden' form that contains a report and / or delete button.

When hovering a comment, the form is shown and it only shows the two buttons.

This works fine. However what i want is for the buttons form to be always in the same place.

At the moment it sits when if the comment text is short, but as soon as the comment is more than 1 line, the div sits underneath the content.

I just want it fixed in the same place, in every single comment div. No matter how many lines it is etc.

Here is a fiddle showing a basic example of what i mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/qzj49/

I just need the form with the buttons in to be fixed, and appear over the text of the comment.

Code just incase:

**CSS:**

```
.textcomment {
    color: #666; width: 98%; 
    padding-left: 1%; 
    padding-right: 1%; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    padding-bottom: 1%; 
    padding-top: 1%; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.textcomment:hover {background-color: #efefef;}
.nocomments {
    width: 100%; 
    color: #888; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    padding-bottom: 1%; 
    padding-top: 1%;
}

.commentActionButton {
display: none;
top: 0;
float:right;
width: 14%;
z-index: 999;
}

.delrepcomment {}

.deletecommentsubmit {
background-color: #F00;
border: none;
color: #fff;
opacity: 0.4;
float:right;
width: 48%;
margin-right: 0%;
padding: 2%;
}

.reportcommentsubmit {
background-color: #F90;
border: none;
color: #fff;
opacity: 0.4;
float:right;
width: 48%;
margin-right: 4%;
padding: 2%;
}

.reportcommentsubmit:hover, .deletecommentsubmit:hover {
opacity: 0.9;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='textcomment'>
    <a class='userights1'>Username:</a>&nbsp;
    This is a comment
    <div class='commentActionButton'>
        <form action='#' method='post' class='delrepcomment'> 
            <input type='hidden' name='delcommentid'>
            <input type='hidden' name='postowner'>
            <input class='deletecommentsubmit' name='submit-delete' value='delete' type='submit'>

        </form> 
        <input class='reportcommentsubmit' name='submit-report' type='submit' value='report'> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class='textcomment'>
    <a class='userights1'>Username:</a>&nbsp;
    This is a comment that extends to more than 1 line long... This is a comment that extends to more than 1 line long... 
    <div class='commentActionButton'>
        <form action='#' method='post' class='delrepcomment'> 
            <input type='hidden' name='delcommentid'>
            <input type='hidden' name='postowner'>
            <input class='deletecommentsubmit' name='submit-delete' value='delete' type='submit'>
        </form> 
        <input class='reportcommentsubmit' name='submit-report' type='submit' value='report'> 
    </div>
</div>

<div class='textcomment'>
    <a class='userights1'>Username:</a>&nbsp;
    This is a comment that extends to more than 2 lines long... This is a comment that extends to more than 2 lines long... This is a comment that extends to more than 2 lines long... This is a comment that extends to more than 2 lines long... 
    <div class='commentActionButton'>
        <form action='#' method='post' class='delrepcomment'> 
            <input type='hidden' name='delcommentid'>
            <input type='hidden' name='postowner'>
            <input class='deletecommentsubmit' name='submit-delete' value='delete' type='submit'>
        </form> 
        <input class='reportcommentsubmit' name='submit-report' type='submit' value='report'> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// Show the delete / report comment on hover
$(".textcomment").hover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);       
    $(this).closest('.textcomment').find('.commentActionButton').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Please post your code here in the question. If jsFiddle went down or for some other reason the target of your link changed content your question would no longer have code associated with it.

Comment: this looks ok to me... not sure that i get your point, i wouldn't change current appearance. However, where you want these buttons exactly?

Comment: The buttons need to be always lets say: 2px from the right, and 2px from the top. Always fixed in that position. But currently, they sit underneath the content in the comment. I have tried giving them a fixed position but they dont show in the div...

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qzj49/1/ ?

Comment: perfect! Thanks! Did you want to post an answer and ill mark as correct?

Comment: Hi! Isn't the input button `submit-report` supposed to be inside the `form` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple set container position to relative, and form div position to absolute:

```
.textcomment {color: #666; width: 98%; padding-left: 1%; padding-right: 1%; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1%; padding-top: 1%; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;position:relative;}
.textcomment:hover {background-color: #efefef;}
.nocomments {width: 100%; color: #888; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom: 1%; padding-top: 1%;}

.commentActionButton {
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    width: 14%;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qzj49/1/